# Better use of Enum.reduce in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to create a query's where clause after where =1=1 in this way

```
Enum.reduce(params, "WHERE 1=1 ", fn param, condition = _acc ->
  {name, value} = param
  cond do
    name == "camera_name" && value != "" -> condition <> "AND LOWER(CAMERA_NAME) ilike lower('%#{value}%')"
    name == "requester_name" && value != "" -> condition <> "AND LOWER(REQUESTER_NAME) ilike lower('%#{value}%')"
    true -> condition
  end
end)
```

and value of params can be like this

```
%{"camera_name" => "gpo", "requester_name" => "junaid"}
```

The above results in this

```
"WHERE 1=1 AND LOWER(CAMERA_NAME) ilike lower('%ju%')"
```

I think there could be a better way of doing this? also I am appending `WHERE 1=1` because I want to append `AND` with it, if you can suggest something good then please do.

Update:

this is the query that I didn't find any way to write in Ecto helpers.

```
  WITH CORE AS (
    SELECT
      'ARCHIVES' AS TAB_NAME,
      ARC.TITLE,
      ARC.EXID,
      ARC.CREATED_AT,
      ARC.FROM_DATE,
      ARC.TO_DATE,
      NULL AS EMBED_CODE,
      ARC.FILE_NAME,
      ARC.FRAMES,
      ARC.URL,
      ARC.PUBLIC,
      ARC.STATUS,
      ARC.TYPE,
      NULL AS EXTRA,
      ARC.REQUESTED_BY,
      ARC.CAMERA_ID
    FROM
      PUBLIC.ARCHIVES AS ARC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'TIMELAPSES',
      TL.TITLE,
      TL.EXID,
      TL.INSERTED_AT,
      TL.FROM_DATETIME,
      TL.TO_DATETIME,
      NULL AS EMBED_CODE,
      NULL AS FILE_NAME,
      NULL AS FRAMES,
      NULL AS URL,
      NULL AS PUBLIC,
      TL.STATUS,
      NULL AS TYPE,
      TL.EXTRA,
      TL.USER_ID,
      TL.CAMERA_ID
    FROM
      PUBLIC.TIMELAPSES AS TL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      'COMPARES',
      COMP.EXID,
      COMP.NAME,
      COMP.INSERTED_AT,
      COMP.BEFORE_DATE,
      COMP.AFTER_DATE,
      COMP.EMBED_CODE,
      NULL AS FILE_NAME,
      NULL AS FRAMES,
      NULL AS URL,
      COMP.PUBLIC,
      COMP.STATUS,
      NULL AS TYPE,
      NULL AS EXTRA,
      COMP.REQUESTED_BY,
      COMP.CAMERA_ID
    FROM
      PUBLIC.COMPARES AS COMP ),
    MORE_INFO AS (
      SELECT
        C.*,
        TRIM(CONCAT(U.FIRSTNAME, ' ', U.LASTNAME)) AS REQUESTER_NAME,
        U.EMAIL AS REQUESTER_EMAIL,
        CAM.EXID AS CAMERA_EXID,
        CAM.NAME AS CAMERA_NAME
      FROM
        CORE C
      JOIN USERS U ON
        C.REQUESTED_BY = U.ID
      JOIN CAMERAS CAM ON
        C.CAMERA_ID = CAM.ID )
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        MORE_INFO
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're concatenating strings for these queries? They look like SQL--is there a reason you aren't using Ecto?

Comment: I would think the easiest way to do this would be just matching on params with private functions that update your acc.

Comment: @BrettBeatty I have added the query which I am trying to do, and I didn't find any way to do it in Ecto Helpers, if you see it possible? I would post another question for it?

Comment: Which part weren't you seeing in helpers? From the docs it looks like Ecto.Query supports WITH https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#with_cte/3

Comment: I had to create a view at last.

Answer (score 2):

Ecto is great for this sort of thing, especially in protecting queries from injection. You can pass around a query and add onto it, so it makes for a great accumulator.

Since your question concatenates a string I'll stick to that. I've done iterations over maps with logic to handle keys, and that works fine (though matching is maybe a better fit than a cond).

But sometimes I prefer piping for stuff like this. Instead of accumulating a string, this example will use a list to make it easier to get rid of your `WHERE 1=1`.

```rb
def construct_query(params) do
  []
  |> where_not_empty(params["camera_name"], &"LOWER(CAMERA_NAME) ilike lower('%#{&1}%')")
  |> where_not_empty(params["requester_name"], &"LOWER(REQUESTER_NAME) ilike lower('%#{&1}%')")
  |> to_query()
end

defp where_not_empty(conditions, param, fun) when byte_size(param) > 0 do
  [fun.(param) | conditions]
end

defp where_not_empty(conditions, _param, _fun) do
  conditions
end

defp to_query([]) do
  ""
end

defp to_query(conditions) do
  "WHERE " <> Enum.join(conditions, " AND ")
end

construct_query(%{})
#=> ""
construct_query(%{"camera_name" => "gpo"})
#=> "WHERE LOWER(CAMERA_NAME) ilike lower('%gpo%')"
construct_query(%{"camera_name" => "gpo", "requester_name" => "junaid"})
#=> "WHERE LOWER(REQUESTER_NAME) ilike lower('%junaid%') AND LOWER(CAMERA_NAME) ilike lower('%gpo%')"
construct_query(%{"requester_name" => "junaid"})
#=> "WHERE LOWER(REQUESTER_NAME) ilike lower('%junaid%')"
```